# Netrenders don't use random seeds

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, network

I recently did a netrender under Cycles with a hundred frames at five samples a frame with random seeds. However, all of the ouputs ended up the same. Why did this happen?

Here's a screenshot of my sampling options:

[image: Sampling Options]

I didn't post the .blend because it's over a gigabyte, but if you need it I can. Similarly, I didn't post the render results because they were 214 MB each, but I can.

#### Edit

I tested it again (both netrender and local) and the netrender again failed to deliver, while the local render worked. Very strange.

#### Another edit

Problem cured itself. No idea why or how. But it did. Someone with enough power can close this now.

Comment: The seed value has nothing to do with the size of your file or the size of the rendered image.

Comment: @zeffii I know that. I'm just saying that the rendered files are large so I didn't post them. However, SEPARATELY, I can't get the seed to randomize.

Comment: try the old method : type "#frame" in the seed value

Comment: @Blithur tried it, no good. http://imgur.com/a/q9XIE